# DBI::dbExecute doesn't send long query and doesn't throw any error

Tags: r, rodbc, r-dbi

`RODBC::sqlQuery` and `DBI::dbExecute` are both standard function to query database in R.
As I want to push a big dataframe in a database table, the push is not done when the dataframe is too big and more dangerous it don't return any error.

Is there other alternative?

Comment: ...well does the function call return at all, or does it just hang?  Also, to put things in perspective, how much data are we talking about here?

Comment: The functions return error code and in this case there are not. it's not the first time that i have seen error not signaled for these packages.. my dataframe is 1208 rows and 14 column (6.2  KB)

Comment: Your data frame is small, as the term "big" would apply in this context.  Can you do a simple select query on any table in the database?  I'll bet you have a connection problem.

Comment: you right is not really big ! it's not a connection problem i can send all the data by sending 50 rows each time for example..

Comment: Are you connecting to a database over a network which has a latency problem (i.e. is really slow)?  Maybe the small amount of data is just taking too long to complete, and the connection is dropping.

Comment: in fact the same query work for RODBC::sqlQuery but not DBI::dbExecute. the non error signal is scaring..

Comment: Then see if you can write a single row from a data frame (i.e. one record).  If even that fails, then maybe the cause is something else.  If that _works_, then check your connection.